# How can you identify the best companies for each variable and copy the cases?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

i want to compare the means of subgroups. The cases of the subgroup with the lowest and the highest mean should be copied and applied to the end of the dataset:

```
Input
df.head(10)

Outcome
Company     Satisfaction    Image   Forecast    Contact
0   Blue    2   3   3   1
1   Blue    2   1   3   2
2   Yellow  4   3   3   3
3   Yellow  3   4   3   2
4   Yellow  4   2   1   5
5   Blue    1   5   1   2
6   Blue    4   2   4   3
7   Yellow  5   4   1   5
8   Red     3   1   2   2
9   Red     1   1   1   2
```

I have around 100 cases in my sample. Now i look at the means for each company.

```
Input
df.groupby(['Company']).mean()

Outcome     
        Satisfaction    Image   Forecast    Contact
Company                 
Blue    2.666667    2.583333    2.916667    2.750000
Green   3.095238    3.095238    3.476190    3.142857
Orange  3.125000    2.916667    3.416667    2.625000
Red     3.066667    2.800000    2.866667    3.066667
Yellow  3.857143    3.142857    3.000000    2.714286
```

So for satisfaction **Yellow** got the best and **Blue** the worst value. I want to copy the cases of yellow and blue and add them to the dataset but now with the new lable "Best" and "Worst". I dont want to rename it and i want to iterate over the dataset and to this for other columns, too (for example Image). Is there a solution for it? After i added the cases i want an output like this:

```
Input
df.groupby(['Company']).mean()

Expected Outcome    
        Satisfaction    Image   Forecast    Contact
Company                 
Blue    2.666667    2.583333    2.916667    2.750000
Green   3.095238    3.095238    3.476190    3.142857
Orange  3.125000    2.916667    3.416667    2.625000
Red     3.066667    2.800000    2.866667    3.066667
Yellow  3.857143    3.142857    3.000000    2.714286
Best    3.857143    3.142857    3.000000    3.142857
Worst   2.666667    2.583333    2.866667    2.625000
```

But how i said. It is really important that the companies with the best and worst values for each column will be added again and not just be renamed because i want to do to further data processing with another software.

************************UPDATE****************************

I found out how to copy the correct cases:

```
Input
df2 = df.loc[df['Company'] == 'Yellow']
df2 = df2.replace('Yellow','Best')
df2 = df2[['Company','Satisfaction']]
new = [df,df2]
result = pd.concat(new)
result

Output
    Company     Contact     Forecast    Image   Satisfaction
0   Blue    1.0     3.0     3.0     2
1   Blue    2.0     3.0     1.0     2
2   Yellow  3.0     3.0     3.0     4
3   Yellow  2.0     3.0     4.0     3
..........................................
87  Best    NaN     NaN     NaN     3
90  Best    NaN     NaN     NaN     4
99  Best    NaN     NaN     NaN     1
111     Best    NaN     NaN     NaN     2
```

Now i want to copy the cases of the company with the best values for the other variables, too. But now i have to identify manually which company is best for each category. Isnt there a more comfortable solution?

Comment: Hey, no not really or what do you mean? The last "Expected outcome" is the one i want after the data transformation.

Comment: Given that you index is Company, you can simply use df.loc['Best'] = df.max()
df.loc['Worst'] = df.min() after df = df.groupby(['Company']).mean()

Comment: Hey, thanks for your anser. But if if i use "df.groupby(['Company'])['Satisfaction'].mean().max()" i get the highest value (3.857142857142857). I cant add this to my dataframe. I need to copy the cases of the company (Yellow) to be added to the dataframe but now with the label "Best".

Comment: I updated the starting post. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution. First i create a dictionary with the variables i want to create a dummy company for best and worst:

```
variables = ['Contact','Forecast','Satisfaction','Image']
```

After i loop over this columns and adding the cases again with the new label "Best" or "Worst":

```
for n in range(0,len(variables),1):
    Start = variables[n-1]
    neu = df.groupby(['Company'], as_index=False)[Start].mean()
    Best = neu['Company'].loc[neu[Start].idxmax()]
    Worst = neu['Company'].loc[neu[Start].idxmin()]
    dfBest = df.loc[df['Company'] == Best]
    dfWorst = df.loc[df['Company'] == Worst]
    dfBest = dfBest.replace(Best,'Best')
    dfWorst = dfWorst.replace(Worst,'Worst')
    dfBest = dfBest[['Company',Start]]
    dfWorst = dfWorst[['Company',Start]]
    new = [df,dfBest,dfWorst]
    df = pd.concat(new)
```

Thanks guys :)